# Prevent ruby selenium-webdriver dismissing alerts when raising UnhandledAlertError

Tags: ruby, selenium, webdriver

Looking at the change-log for ruby selenium-webdriver I found this line under 2.18.0:

- Firefox and IE:

  - Raise UnhandledAlertError if an alert is present during an operation. The unhandled alert is also dismissed to mitigate repeat exceptions.

In my opinion this is an awful change. I like the exception, but any unhandled confirms are dismissed (returned false).
I'd quite like to be able to rescue the exception and handle the confirm myself.

Unfortunately I cannot find the code in the selenium-webdriver gem so I can overwrite this section and get rid of the dismiss alert command.

Any way round this (other than reverting my version)?

Thanks in advance,

Arth

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure that this is what you are after but maybe I will help anyway. The way I understand you question is that you want 'force' a rescue for unhandled alerts.

When using an assertion such as the find element function because of time-outs me i am using the following code to repeatedly search for the element.

```
!20.times { break if (selenium.is_visible(driver.find_element(:id, 'loginid')) rescue false ) ; sleep 1 }
```

The above will loop 20 times (waiting 1 sec each time) in an attempt to find and element and break when it does find it. Notice that I am not rescuing it yet as it is more robust to place this between begin/end. Something like this..:

```
    begin           
!20.times { break if (selenium.is_visible(driver.find_element(:id, 'loginid')) rescue false ) ; sleep 1 }

[your executing code here]      .
      .
      .
usr = driver.find_element(:id, 'loginid').click         
usr = driver.find_element(:id, 'loginid').send_keys(username)
      .
      .
rescue
      .
      .
[your rescure code here]
      .
      .

puts "____________________________________________________________________"
puts "*** FATAL ERROR --> located at login area (username/password) ***"
puts "Possible reasons for this error..:"
puts "Invalid credentials * Cannot locate element id * "
puts "____________________________________________________________________"
     .
end
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: That has nothing to do with the problem at hand.  The problem is this: http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=3392